Why the compiler still complains even if std::mutex has been used when `-fsanitize=thread -ltsan` are enabled?
Why the compiler complain about this code snippet when -std=c++11 -lpthread -fsanitize=thread -ltsan are enabled?
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mtx;

void checkAndUse(std::weak_ptr<int> weakPtr) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    if (auto sharedPtr = weakPtr.lock()) {
        std::cout << "Using shared resource: " << *sharedPtr << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Shared resource has been destroyed." << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto sharedPtr = std::make_shared<int>(1);
    std::weak_ptr<int> weakPtr = sharedPtr;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back(checkAndUse, weakPtr);
    }

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        sharedPtr.reset(); // Destroy the shared resource
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }

    return 0;
}

Here is what the compiler complains:
FATAL: ThreadSanitizer: unexpected memory mapping 0x71f4f1272000-0x71f4f1700000


Removing -ltsan fixes this. You don't need to link it manually, passing -fsanitize=thread to the linker too is enough.

Why adding -ltsan causes the compiler complain about unexpected memory mapping? And gcc still complains after removing.

I don't know, maybe it links a wrong LSAN library somehow.

On GCC switching to -std=c++14 or newer helps. Not sure why.

-std=c++23 still reproduces the same error for GCC.

Hmm, it seems it crashes randomly (in GCC). I can reproduce locally. I'd report a bug to GCC

@HolyBlackCat  I see. thank you. 1. Do you agree that the code snippet (posted in my question) has no data race? 2. Do you think the code snippet works well without any mutex?

The code looks ok to me, even without the mutex. Even if it was a data race, the sanitizer should report it properly rather than crash.

@John there is no race, with or without the mutex. The mutex is not useful here because you never change the shared resource, treating it as a constant, while the refcounting itself is threadsafe anyway.
